# In React @rjsf/core, How to pass custom props for "ui:widget"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, schema, react-props

In react app, I am using `@rjsf/core` `Form` and passing schema from backend like

```
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "emailAddress": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "format": "idn-email"
    },
    "password": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 16,
      "maxLength": 50
    },
    "passwordResetLink": {
      "default": "http://localhost:8080/passwordReset",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "emailAddress",
    "password"
  ]
}
```

and uiSchema is like

```
    "ui:submitButtonOptions": {
      props: {
        disabled: false,
        className: "btn btn-warning",
      },
      submitText: formConstants.buttons.LOGIN,
    },
    emailAddress: {
      "ui:options": {
        label: false,
        placeholder: formConstants.requiredFields.EMAIL,
      },
    },
    password: {
      "ui:widget": "password",
      "ui:options": {
        label: false,
        placeholder: formConstants.requiredFields.PASSWORD,
      },
    },
    passwordResetLink: {
      "ui:options": {
        label: false,
      },
      "ui:widget": CustomForgotPasswordField,
    },
  };
```

CustomForgotPasswordField is like,

```
const CustomForgotPasswordField = (props) => {
  const linkText = props.passwordResetLinkText || "Hello";
  const linkUrl = props.passwordResetLinkUrl || "www";

  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <p>
        <a href={linkUrl}>{linkText}</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default CustomForgotPasswordField;
```

Link UI is displaying based on my requirement but I want to pass Link and Text dynamically from outside of a component. So I want to use it as props here but right now props are not supporting.

If I change `"ui:widget": CustomForgotPasswordField` then whole link UI will go off.

Please help me to achieve this